# Functor for applying an arbitrary member function to a container of containers of objects

Tags: c++, boost, functor, boost-bind

We're transitioning to C++11 but still a few months away.  Please feel free to  give C++11 responses, but we're curious whether there's a non-ugly way to do it in C++98/03.

---

A co-worker came to me with code resembling:

```
typedef void(B::*fptr_t)();

void A::my_foreach( uint idx, fptr_t fptr ) {
  for( iter_type iter = asdf[idx].begin(); iter != asdf[idx].end(); ++iter )
    iter->second->*fptr();
}

void A::get( uint idx ) { my_foreach( idx, &B::get ); }
void A::get( uint idx ) { my_foreach( idx, &B::get ); }
```

... asking if there was a better way, to which I responded with:

```
void A::get( uint idx ) {
  std::for_each( asdf[idx].begin()
               , asdf[idx].end()
               , boost::bind( &B::get, _1 ) );
}
void A::put( uint idx ) {
  std::for_each( asdf[idx].begin()
               , asdf[idx].end()
               , boost::bind( &B::put, _1 ) );
}
```

... but that still left me feeling like more could be done to avoid code duplication.  The general solutions that have occurred to me are:

1. Re-factor the code so the involved classes have less responsibilities, and wrap the container(s) in decorator/proxy objects that provide some of the needed functionality.
2. Generic `apply to my container` member function that takes the intended function as an argument (that is, callers must provide the function)
3. Make two private member functions: the function mentioned in (2) and one to return a functor to call it, then public functor objects initialized in the constructor.
4. Use `boost::bind` to wrap the whole thing, making a functor that could be used like this:

.

```
functor_t get = my_binder( &B::get );
functor_t put = my_binder( &B::put );
```

... where `my_binder` would produce an object that can perform the same operations, but that quickly got ugly because of how many functions are actually executing in the above code (`operator[]`, `X::begin`, `X::end`, `something for applying the function ptr to each element of the container`).

Is there another/better way prior to C++11, or are those solutions pretty much what's available?

Comment: You can replace `boost::bind( &B::get, _1 )` with `std::mem_fun(&B::get)`, and then write a function that takes a `std::mem_fun_t<void, B>`

Answer (score 1):

`std::mem_fn` is the binder from step 4.

You didn't quite *mention* the fact that your container looks to be associative (e.g. `std::map`). I'd suggest using Boost Range for adapting ranges to project to the mapped values:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2913f445e036a8a4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;

template<typename T> struct Container {
    template <typename F> void my_foreach(uint idx, F&& f) {
        boost::for_each(_data[idx] | map_values, std::forward<F>(f));
    }

    std::map<int, std::map<int, T> > _data;
};

#include <iostream>
struct B {
    B(std::string s) : _s(s) {}
    void foo()      const { std::cout << "foo(" << _s << ")\n"; }
    void bar(int i) const { std::cout << "bar(" << _s << ", " << i << ")\n"; }
  private:
    std::string _s;
};

#include <functional>
int main() {
    Container<B> c;
    c._data = { // just some demo data
        { 1, { { 100, {"hundred"} }, { 1000, {"thousand"} }, { 1000000, {"million"} }, } },
        { 2, { { 100, {"hundert"} }, { 1000, {"tausend"} }, { 1000000, {"miljon"} }, } },
        { 3, { { 100, {"cent"} }, { 1000, {"mille"} }, { 1000000, {"million"} }, } },
        { 4, { { 100, {"honderd"} }, { 1000, {"duizen"} }, { 1000000, {"miljoen"} }, } },
    };

    c.my_foreach(3, std::mem_fn(&B::foo));
    c.my_foreach(1, [](B const& b) { b.bar(42); });
}
```

Printing:

```
foo(cent)
foo(mille)
foo(million)
bar(hundred, 42)
bar(thousand, 42)
bar(million, 42)
```

Comment: In the actual code I think it's `vector<vector<TheType> >`, but the question at this point is more academic so I left out the exact container type because I'm more interested in learning something new than getting a solution to that particular problem (he's using it with duplicated code to avoid spending a lot of time researching this).

Comment: Well, your code has `iter->second` so it only makes sense if `TheType` happens to be like `std::pair<T, U>`. You can still use the `map_values` adaptor then (I think). If all that was irrelevant, then perhaps `std::mem_fn` was the answer indeed.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't really been thinking too deeply about the containers used.  I'll have to tinker with mem_fn & get a better idea of what it does.